# how to change default structure in zend studio

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

when I create a new project in zend studio it creates structure as follows:
application
    -controllers
    -models
    -views

I would like it to follow modular pattern
application
    -module
        -controllers
        -models
        -forms
        -views

So e.g. modules might be default and admin.
Any help much appreciated